# does the operator that has a pair of vertical lines to compute cardinality of a set have a name? if yes, what it is?

Tags: notation, machine-learning

I am learning this [post.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/53429/74719)

the $|D|$ in formula

$$\alpha=\frac{\left|D_{1}\right|}{\left|D\right|}$$

means the cardinality of the set D.

does this operator have a name? if yes, what it is?

Comment: I think that the "operator" has no better name than [Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also written  $\operatorname{card}D$. So it is natural to call the operator *card*, following the convention of calling the logarithm, cosine, tangent (etc.) functions after their standard abbreviations log, cos, tan, and so on.